# pfSense: config with daloRadius (freeRadius) to setup download quota limitation

Tags: pfsense, radius, freeradius, rate-limiting, quota

I have pfsense and daloRadius(running freeRadius inside) up and running, I successfully configured radius parameters on pfSense and the NAS on daloRadius and they can talk to each other.

I am able to create users from daloRadius and authenticate them from pfSense.
But when I add some attributes for bandwidth limitation or download quota limitation, authentication fails from pfSense.

Plus in spite of all the search i did, am' not able to understand clearly how radius attributes function:
- Difference between `check` and `reply` and when to use either
- also the operators being used.

Since i didn't understand clearly i tried all combinations that made sense to me but it never worked, I always get `access-reject`.

I added to daloRadius the pfSense radius attribute  dictionary which i got from  [here](https://github.com/pfsense/pfsense/blob/master/src/usr/share/doc/radius/dictionary.pfsense):

```
VENDOR      pfSense             13644

BEGIN-VENDOR    pfSense

ATTRIBUTE   pfSense-Bandwidth-Max-Up        1   integer
ATTRIBUTE   pfSense-Bandwidth-Max-Down      2   integer
ATTRIBUTE   pfSense-Max-Total-Octets        3   integer

END-VENDOR pfSense
```

but whenever I create a user and try using one of these attributes in either `reply` or `check` attribute, the user is not authorised when logging in, just getting `access-reject` with no explanations.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you using pfsenses built in pppoe server? If so then the bandwith limiting commands are here in this post by me: [enter link description here](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/141034/rate-limit-on-radius-reply-attributes-for-pppoe-connections-not-working)